# How to check from command line if audio file has any sound

Tags: command-line, sound

I want to check if an audio file has any voice in it (it's not mute, or better if it has a human sound).

For example if when use a recording application - I want to check if it has any voice in it, can the info about the Bit Rate help me?.

Is there any application that can give this information - (without listening)? Even if it's not command line based I would like to know, but I prefer a command line tool

Comment: With "voice" do you mean "any sound" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like 'sox' for this

```
sox myaudio.mp3 stat | grep "Maximum amplitude"
```

I haven't tested it, since I am away from my Ubu-box.

Comment: Thanks @Soren A Would you please elaborate regarding this command - what it returns, and how can I investigate more about the sox program.

Comment: You can try 'man sox' in a terminal on your Ubuntu, or google for 'man sox'. Also google can provide other examples of sox usage.

Comment: In my version of sox, I need to add `-n` as output file or I get an error "Not enough input filenames specified". But `sox myaudio.mp3 -n stat` works.

Comment: 6000 mp3s and some of them are silent, this is a god send -- it's only taken me about a hour to find this solution! :D